# submenu not working in dropdown menu css

Tags: css

I have made a dropdown menu with rollover image. The rollover image almost works (Benedict Cumberbatch is meant to turn into an otter) and a submenu to drop down (which at the moment doesn't appear).

What have I done wrong? Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7DcH/1/)

The HTML >>

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#" class="about"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/bw1wxme/Lgsmzv53i/rollover-1.jpg"></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">1.2.1.1. Sub-Level-3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">1.2.1.2. Sub-Level-3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">1.2.1.3. Sub-Level-3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">1.2.1.4. Sub-Level-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

The CSS >>

```
 #nav {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 3em 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 opacity:1;
 }
 #nav li {
 float: left; }
 #nav li a {
  display: block;
 padding: 8px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #069;
 }
 #nav li a:hover {
 color: #c00;
 background-color: #fff;
 }

 #nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
display:none; 
 }

 #nav .about:hover {background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/bw1wxme/RjMmzv543/rollover-2.jpg');}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this to your css:

```
#nav li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

To show it when hover

Updated **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7DcH/2/)**